# Get average based on input with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get average from an input.

I have 5 input fields. I want to do something like this :

```
n = total of inputed field (has value)
total = n1 + n2 + ... + n5 / n
```

For example:

```
1 + 2 + 3 / 3
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 / 4
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 / 5
```

The average is based on how much user input the textfield. Here is what I tried so far. Please check it.

**With my script below . I only able to sum and i can't do the `average`**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".kd1", function() {
    $('table tr').each(function() {
      var valid_labels = 0;
      var newval = 0;
      var total = $('.kd1', this).get().reduce(function(sum, elem) {
        return sum + +$(elem).val();
      }, 0)
      if (!isNaN(total)) {
        valid_labels += 1;
        newval += total;
      }
      $('.result1', this).val(newval / valid_labels);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'></td>
    <td><input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'></td>
    <td><input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'></td>
    <td><input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'></td>
    <td><input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'></td>
    <td><input type='text' size='5' class='result1'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'></td>
    <td><input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'></td>
    <td><input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'></td>
    <td><input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'></td>
    <td><input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'></td>
    <td><input type='text' size='5' class='result1'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

sorry for my bad english.

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14899614/6354277

Comment: Is there a specific issue with the code you wrote that you need help with?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I only able to sum and i can't do the average

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over input fields, add values which are non-empty along with that increment the count.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("input", ".kd1", function() {
    $('table tr').each(function() {
      // variables for holding total and count
      var total = 0,
        count = 0;

      // get all input fields and iterate over them
      $('.kd1', this).each(function() {
        // check the value is non-empty
        if (this.value.trim() != '') {
          // increment count for calculating average
          count++;
          // update total based on input value
          // treat input value as 0 if number parsing produces NaN
          total += (Number(this.value.trim()) || 0);
        }
      });
      // calculate and update the average although treat as zero if NaN
      $('.result1', this).val(total / count || 0);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='result1'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='kd1'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' size='5' class='result1'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You forgot to ignore the blanks inputs in your calculation

Comment: When a input has no value, he should be ignored in your calculation, no ? If I enter 2 and 4 in the first row, the average is 1.2, but it should be 3. The question specify  `n     = total of inputed field (has value)`, so shouldn't you ignore the ones wich hasn't ?